# Postfix + Dovecot: Create send-only email account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I've got a nice little mail server setup (running Ubuntu Server 16.04) that works a treat. It uses postfix as SMTP, which uses dovecot (IMAP) as an authentication source for virtual mailbox users.

It's been working fine, but now I have a second server in another location (with a dynamic IP address), which I'd like to be able to send mail through my main mail server. I've [seen a guide](https://www.lunanode.com/tutorial/postfix_smtp_secure) on setting it up in authenticated-relay mode, and am part-way through the process, but then I realised that I'd need a send-only email account for it to authenticate against, as I don't want it to be able to receive mail and fill up the server's hard drive (I won't check the inbox!).

How can I create a new email account in my virtual users setup that doesn't have a mailbox, but can still connect via SMTP and send emails?

Comment: you can ADD additional authentication backends, see http://www.postfix.org/SOHO_README.html

Comment: @JacobEvans So the `smtp_sasl_password_maps` option would add additional user / password combinations that my satellite server to send mail as?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add the user just like any other user, but  restrict recipient. This will give an error during `RCPT TO` regardless whether the user actually exists or not.

For example, if a web page of a company might send some emails using `websiteuser@example.com` as a sender address, while no-one should read that address but only their `first.last@example.com` addresses, and the server has `mydestination = example.com` that would normally deliver to that user, I'd simply add (without removing what there already is in [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions)):

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    . . .
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access/denied_recipients,
    . . .
```

> `check_recipient_access type:table`
>
> Search the specified [access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html)
>   database for the resolved `RCPT TO` address, domain, parent domains, or
>   `localpart@`, and execute the corresponding action.

Then add the unallowed addresses there with a friendly and human readable reason for the reject:

```
websiteuser@example.com    REJECT    Visit the web site for correct contact information.
helpdesksite@example.com   REJECT    Please log in and use the helpdesk contact form.
```

That should work what ever is the reason you don't want to accept mail for an address. Remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/access/denied_recipients` as the lookup table is a [`hash` type Berkeley DB](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types).

Comment: This sounds like a great solution, thanks! I'll investigate. If it works, I'll mark it as the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Yep, this works. It's important to note that postfix, when parsing `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, will run through the list of restrictions and utilise the first one it finds - and will ignore all the rest. So if you have a rule that says "allow everyone who's logged in" _before_ this new `check_recipient_access` rule, it will follow the allow logged in users rule for accounts local to the server and ignore the new one.

Comment: True. You have done your homework well! :)

Comment: If you would like to store this information in mysql, you can add a bool `receive` field to your virtual user table, set `check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-recipient-access.cf` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and write a query at `mysql-recipient-access.cf` like `SELECT 'REJECT' as action FROM virtual_users WHERE email = '%s' AND receive = 0;`.

Comment: @TCB13 : Great, but how to pass the reason with MySQL ?